# Does Spark support the WITH clause like SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-3.0

I have table `employee_1` in Spark with attributes id and name(with data), and another table, `employee_2`, with the same attributes. I want to load the data by increasing the id values with +1.

### My *WITH* clause is shown below:

```
WITH EXP AS (SELECT  ALIASNAME.ID+1 ID, ALIASNAME.NAME NAME FROM employee_1 ALIASNAME)
INSERT INTO TABLE employee_2 SELECT * FROM EXP;
```

### Steps of execution:

I have a file (with data) in an HDFS location.

1. Creating an RDD based on the HDFS location.
2. RDD to a Hive temporary table
3. From the temporary table to the Hive Target (employee_2).

When I am running with a test program from the backend, it’s succeeding. But the data is not loading. `employee_2` is empty.

Note:

If you run the above *WITH* clause in Hive, it will succeed and the data will load. But in Spark it won't in 1.6. Why?

Comment: On Spark 2.x it definitely supports WITH statements. I can try to dust off my old 1.6 to verify for you but fundamentally it looks like it should run

Comment: Thanks, Used 1.6, 2.x versions working.. in sparksql context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WITH statement is not the problem, but rather the INSERT INTO statement that's causing trouble.

Here's a working example that uses the .insertInto() style instead of the "INSERT INTO" SQL:

```scala
val s = Seq((1,"foo"), (2, "bar"))
s: Seq[(Int, String)] = List((1,foo), (2,bar))
val df = s.toDF("id", "name")
df.registerTempTable("df")
sql("CREATE TABLE edf_final (id int, name string)")
val e = sql("WITH edf AS (SELECT id+1, name FROM df cook) SELECT * FROM edf")
e.insertInto("edf_final")
```

Another option is to use the `df.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("edf_final")` style.

Relevant SO: ["INSERT INTO ..." with SparkSQL HiveContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923348/insert-into-with-sparksql-hivecontext)

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer is for Spark 2.x,
I am rewriting it in the Spark 3 way.

```
%scala

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val s = Seq((1,"foo"), (2, "bar"))
val df = s.toDF("id", "name")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE if not exists edf_final (id int, name string)")
val e = spark.sql("WITH edf AS (SELECT id+1 AS id, name FROM df) SELECT * FROM edf")
e.select(col("id"), col("name")).write.insertInto("edf_final")

spark.sql("select * from edf_final").show
```

Result:

```
df:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
id:integer
name:string
e:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
id:integer
name:string
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  2| foo|
|  3| bar|
+---+----+
```