# Spark sql issue with columns specified

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

we are trying to replicate an oracle db into hive. We get the queries from oracle and run them in hive.
So, we get them in this format:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table(col1,col2) VALUES ('val','val');
```

While this query works in Hive directly, when I use spark.sql, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input 'emp_id' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'VALUES', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'MAP', 'REDUCE'}(line 1, pos 20)
== SQL ==
insert into ss.tab(emp_id,firstname,lastname) values ('1','demo','demo')
--------------------^^^
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:623)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:691)
        at com.datastream.SparkReplicator.insertIntoHive(SparkReplicator.java:20)
        at com.datastream.App.main(App.java:67)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:755)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: Also, the command works with spark.sql(insert into ss.tab(val1,val2) directly. Any solutions? Or a way to strip the query of (col1,col2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is coming as Spark SQL does not support column lists in the insert statement. so exclude the column list from the insert statement.

below was my hive table:

```
select * from UDB.emp_details_table;
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+--+
| emp_id  | emp_name  | emp_dept  | emp_joining_date  |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+--+
| 1       | AAA       | HR        | 2018-12-06        |
| 1       | BBB       | HR        | 2017-10-26        |
| 2       | XXX       | ADMIN     | 2018-10-22        |
| 2       | YYY       | ADMIN     | 2015-10-19        |
| 2       | ZZZ       | IT        | 2018-05-14        |
| 3       | GGG       | HR        | 2018-06-30        |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+--+
```

## here I am inserting record using spark sql through pyspark

```
df = spark.sql("""insert into UDB.emp_details_table values ('6','VVV','IT','2018-12-18')""");
```

you could see below that given record has been inserted to my existing hive table.

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+--+
| emp_id  | emp_name  | emp_dept  | emp_joining_date  |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+--+
| 1       | AAA       | HR        | 2018-12-06        |
| 1       | BBB       | HR        | 2017-10-26        |
| 2       | XXX       | ADMIN     | 2018-10-22        |
| 2       | YYY       | ADMIN     | 2015-10-19        |
| 2       | ZZZ       | IT        | 2018-05-14        |
| 3       | GGG       | HR        | 2018-06-30        |
| 6       | VVV       | IT        | 2018-12-18        |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+--+
```

change your spark sql query as :

```
spark.sql("""insert into ss.tab values ('1','demo','demo')""");
```

> Note: I am using spark 2.3, you need to use hive context in case you
>   are using spark 1.6 version.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, I followed a similar path. I stripped the columns using some string ops since I received the query at runtime, Thanks anyway.